# Problems with Console Kotlin input

Tags: input, kotlin, console, console-application

Code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("I'm running")
    val str = readLine()
    var sum = 0
    val arr: IntArray
    if (str != null) {
        arr = str.split(" ").map(String::toInt).toIntArray()
        for (ch in arr)
            sum += ch
        println(sum)
    }
    println("not running anymore")
}
```

INPUT:

```
56 -44 -72 -79 -38 -80 4 -85 34 -56 -92 51 36 -12 59 -43 31 17 -76 -8 -52 28 45 -68 -96 -7 -70 20
```

And here is what I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at KotKt.main(kot.kt:8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably trim your input.

Instead of

```
str.split(" ")
```

you should use

```
str.trim().split(" +")
```

---

The `String#trim()` method removes leading and trailing whitespace characters, which lead to your error. Also the additional `+` in the RegEx of the `String#split(regex)` method has the effect that the program will still read the input correctly, and therefore not crash, even if you use multiple blanks as a separator between numbers in the string.

For example, even this input will work:

```
val str = "   1  2 -54  4 811 33      44 4 321 87   "
```